# How to display uptime in i3status bar?

Tags: i3, uptime

I would like to display uptime in common units (so not just in minutes if it is over an hour; also not just in seconds if it is over a minute; e.g., "1:02:30" for 1 hour, 2 minutes and 30 seconds would be my ideal time format) in my i3status bar. I have not even been able to find how to show uptime in the i3status bar in any units. I found [this repo](https://github.com/lenzirodrigo/.i3) on GitHub that seemed to claim to do this but copying these configs gave me errors related to difficulty executing the `status_command` line in this [repo's config](https://github.com/lenzirodrigo/.i3/blob/master/config#L190). Namely the `status_command` line is:

```
status_command ~/.i3/i3status.sh ~/.i3/i3status.conf
```

guessing it only works with an older version of i3. Any ideas how to do this? [here](https://github.com/fusion809/i3-configs/blob/fccf0118e0518db058f5acd807a4e471b6d78399/.i3status.conf) is my present `~/.i3status.conf` file. My distribution is Gentoo Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. I simply did not understand its syntax well enough. I just had to edit my `~/.i3/i3status.sh` file. It is now:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/i3status -c $HOME/.i3status.conf | while :
do
    read line
    RAM=`free -kh | grep Mem | awk '{print $3}'`
    TOTR=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemT | sed 's/.*\://g' | sed 's/ *//g' | sed 's/kB//g')
    TOT=$(octave --eval "$TOTR/1024^2" | sed 's/ans = *//g' | sed 's/$/G/g' )

    # Put uptime
    uptime=`uptime | awk '{print $3 " " $4}' | sed 's/,.*//'`
    hour=$(echo $uptime | sed 's/\:.*//g')
    min=$(echo $uptime | sed 's/.*\://g')
    UP="$hour h $min m"

    # Compile C++ CPU prog and run it
    g++ -o cpu.o $HOME/.i3/cpu.cpp
    CPU=$(./cpu.o)

    printf "%s\n" "Up: $UP | CPU: $CPU% | RAM: $RAM/$TOT | $line"
done
```

The most relevant lines to uptime are between `# Put uptime` and `# Compile C++...` and the final `printf "%s\n"...` command. My complete i3 configuration files can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/fusion809/i3-configs).

Comment: Be aware that this solution leads to quite the PID waste, as every tick (as configured via the interval option of i3status) creates a new process for every executable called in the wrapper. Also RAM info can be displayed natively via i3status (see [memory](https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_memory)). Also why the `awk`/`sed` hassle for uptime when you can just call `uptime -p`? Further compiling the cpu app on every tick seems rather insane, especially since i3status provide a built-in for CPU usage (see [CPU usage](https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_cpu_usage))

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

make script in cron.hourly to create formated `/tmp/uptime` in every one hour (I don't need more precision than one hour) and use in i3status with readfile:

```
read_file uptime {
        path = "/tmp/uptime"
}
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{printf("Up %dd:%02d\n",($1/60/60/24),($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60),($1%60))}' /proc/uptime > /tmp/uptime
```